# Perforce - marking local file as latest revision

Tags: perforce

I've got a following problem:
There are many huge files(gigabytes) on repository, they are not yet in my workspace, but I already have them on my local disk from other source(the same copy as the latest revision).

Is there any possibility to move these local files to appropriate subdirectory of my workspace and mark them on P4 server, that they are the same as latest revision, so I don't have to download them again?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [p4 flush](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.2/manuals/cmdref/flush.html) command should do the trick here. In this situation, you would copy the files to the appropriate location in your workspace, then run:

```
p4 flush //path/to/file.ext#head
```

You can do an entire folder using:

```
p4 flush //path/to/folder/...@changelist
```